# CPU stress testing by percentage with native linux command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface, cpu

I am currently running the following commands to stress test my CPU:

```
md5sum /dev/zero
```

Then I kill the process after 30 seconds.

```
pkill md5sum
```

I am looking to run a similar command but where it lets me stress the CPU by a certain percentage. I cannot use libraries like stress-ng, it has to be be able to run with basic linux distro like ubuntu.  I also can't run a program as such, I have to be able to run it from the command line itself. Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible without installing a tool (like `cpulimit`, available in Ubuntu apt repo) or by using [cgroups](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/cgroups.7.html), which is complex to configure and potentially requires kernel rebuilding.

The nearest standard feature is [nice](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/nice.1posix.html), which essentially sets the process priority. So without anything else running, it would still use all the CPU time, but any other processes would get CPU priority.